# How to make a json from youtube api v3 with a wp_cron

Tags: json, wordpress, youtube, cron

I'm  doing a cron job in wordpress and it only worked once, it sent me an email but it never created the json file.
I want to save in a json file data from youtube api v3 in order not make petitions each time because youtube limit the petitions so I thought it will be convenient make a cache job with wp cron but this code is not working. I not sure where is the problem.

```
  function isa_add_every_three_minutes( $schedules ) {

      $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
              'interval'  => 180,
              'display'   => __( 'Every 3 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
      );

      return $schedules;
  }

  add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' );

  if ( !wp_next_scheduled('hook_saveVideos') ) {
     wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'hook_saveVideos' );
  }

  function saveVideos() {

      $channel_id = "channelExample";
      $user_id = "example";
      $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=30&playlistId=".$cv_id."&key=".$user_id;

      $data = file_get_contents($url);
      $videos = json_decode($data, true); 
      $videos = $videos['items'];

      $dVideos = array();

      for ($i=0; $i < count($videos) ; $i++) { 

          $title = $videos[$i]['snippet']['title'];
          $description = $videos[$i]['snippet']['description'];
          $videoId = $videos[$i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];

          $id = "v".$i;

          $dVideos[$id] = array("title"=>$title, "description"=>$description, "videoId"=>$videoId);

      }
      $ruta = "http://localhost/example/cache";
      $fp = fopen($ruta, 'w');
      fwrite($fp, json_encode($dVideos ));
      fclose($fp);



     wp_mail('user@example.com', 'Mail mandado por el cron', 'Hola, esto es un correo enviado automáticamente');
  }
```

Comment: Can you debug your where your file paths are going? It may be somewhere you are not expecting. It's going to be hard to help unless you debug as much of this as possible and put the results as comments above the lines of code.

Comment: I have been checking the path and that was the problem. Thanks for your suggestions.